# file upload using multer in MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, multer

Is there any working snippet of `file-upload` to `mongoDB` using `multer` in `MERN` stack, with latest `multer` `npm` package.

Comment: Go through [How to Upload Files using the MERN stack and Multer.](https://harcourt.hashnode.dev/how-to-upload-files-using-the-mern-stack-and-multer) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const Product = (props) => {
    const [pic, setPic] = useState(null);
    const onChangeProductPic = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        setPic(file);
      }
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("pic", pic);
    


return(
    <div className="form-group">
     //This is form input cannot write whole code you can get it from bootstrap etc.
      <Input
        type="file"
        multiple="false"
        name="pic" 
        onChange={onChangePic}/>
    </div>     
   )};


   //Routes from backend
    router.post('/', multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000 * 1 * 3000
    }
}).single('pic'), userRequestHandler(postData));
```